# Different singular points on different representations of a surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Find the singular points of

$x=u^3, y=v^2, z=uv$$\hspace{1cm}$for $0\le u<\infty$ and $-\infty<v<\infty$

Let's call this surface $\Gamma$, so the singular points $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ are those which $\Gamma_u \times \Gamma_v = \vec0$

$\implies \Gamma_u \times \Gamma_v = (-2v^2,-3u^3,6u^2v) = (0,0,0)$ $\implies u=v=0$ $\implies x_0=y_0=z_0=0$

So the only singular point is $(0,0,0)$.

*but...*

An implicit representation of the surface would be $F(x,y,z)=x^2y^3-z^6$, so the singular points $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ are those which $|F_x(x_0,y_0,z_0)|+|F_y(x_0,y_0,z_0)|+|F_z(x_0,y_0,z_0)|=0$

$\implies |2x_0y_0^3|+|3x_0^2y_0^2|+|-6z_0^5|=0 \implies z_0=0$ and ($x_0=0$ or $y_0=0$)

So the singular points are $(0,y_0,0)$ ($y_0$ may take any value) and $(x_0,0,0)$ ($x_0$ may take any value).

*and...*

with the implicit representation $F(x,y,z)=x^{1/3}y^{1/2}-z$ and proceeding like above, I get that there are no singular points.

So what is happening? Which answer should I take?

Comment: If $\nabla F \neq 0$ on a level set, this level set is a regular surface. But if $\nabla F =0$ on some points of the level set, it still could be a regular surface. For instance, $F(x,y,z)=x^2$. We have that $F^{-1}(0)$ is the plane $x=0$, and $\nabla F(x,0,0)=(0,0,0)$ for all $x$.